# Creating searchable "tags" within body of document

Tags: search-results, metadata

I am writing a set of documents using MS-Word.  The docs will be managed by SharePoint.

I know that SharePoint can search the text in the body of each Word doc.  However, a full text search will return many not very useful hits. I want to limit the search to what I will call “key terms”.

I also know how to tell SharePoint about metadata in Word > File > Info > Properties > Tags field so that these can come up in a user search of the documents from within SharePoint.  However, these fields are difficult to edit in Word (you have a very small window into which you can put a lot of terms).

Can I somehow mark the key terms within the body of a Word document such that SharePoint will treat those key terms the same way it does a Properties Tag field and return them in a search?  I was hoping to turn my table of contents lines into key terms and was hoping SharePoint could similarly see terms that I bookmark in Word.  Any ideas?

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for this purpose the "tags" are not contained in the body of the document but stored with the Library Item as metadata. You can use Content Types and Metadata to describe the document. You can create columns and store the relevant data in those columns. From an enterprise perspective, using Managed Metadata and the MMS field type is preferred since the organization can pull from a central store of metadata values to describe the document attributes.